# Equivariant matrices and commutation relations

Tags: matrices, group-theory

Let $T_1,T_2\in R^{d\times k}$ matrices and $G$ a finite unitary group of cardinality $N$. Indicating (a matrix representation of the) elements of $G$ with $g$,  equivariant matrices can be written as:
$$
C_{s}=\sum_{i=1}^{N} g_{i}T_sT_s^Tg_{i}^T,\;\;s=1,2
$$ 
In fact the matrix has the property that $[C_{s},g_{i}]=0\;\;\forall\;i$ (is equivariant).

I am interested in:

1) find a demonstration for the fact (true? I checked numerically with $10^9$ examples and some permutation groups and it seems so) that for any $T_1,T_2$ and given group
$$[C_1,C_2]=0$$
A possible explanation is that both $C_1$ and $C_2$ are block diagonalized by the generalized Fourier, correct?

2) characterizing the set of unitary matrices $U$ such that for any given $T_1,T_2$ and $G$,

$$[UC_1U^T,C_2]=0$$

Thanks!

Fabio